# Is there a way to compare two different datasets using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare the same dataset for two different days, to see the changes between those two days.

I can currently do it with formulas but as the dataset is quite large the process takes very long and the formulas take a very long time to update.

The dataset is about 5000 rows (changes depending on the day) and 412 columns (fixed), I only need to use 5 of those columns to compare the data.

What I am currently doing:

Filter out data I dont need
Concatenate 2 columns to get the value I want to compare between the two dates.
Using that new  column do a Sumif for dataset1 then delete duplicates.
I repeat the process for dataset2.
Then to find the differences: Sumif(dataset1) - sumif(dataset2)

I have tried doing this on vba but I am lost after making 2 arrays, one for each dataset. 
Is there a way of doing this process in vba?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have a look at Get & Transform, in the Data tab.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will look into it. To clarify the 2 datasets are currently in excel workbooks.

Comment: without looking at your file it's hard to understand what you want to achieve, upload a picture, the formula that is taking time to process, etc.